# Oracle: FRM-41211 Error Message when starting a Report from Oracle Forms (64 Bit Windows Server)

Tags: oracle, 64-bit

After installing Oracle Forms and Reports 6.0 (Patch 18) on a Windows 2008 64 Bit server we get the following error when we try to start a report from Forms.

*"FRM-41211 integration error: ssl failure running another product"*

The problem is reproducable on another server using the same Windows OS.

One of the proposed solutions (extending the REPORTS60_PATH) we have already tried but that did not help solving our problem.
Another tip has been to shorten the content of the path variable before installing Oracle Forms and Reports. We will try this later on another server.

Any other tips or solutions for this error would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I did find a workaround for this problem.

I had to replace two dll files (nn60.dll and nnb60.dll) with the same files of an older forms version (patch 3 or older).

I found this solution and the dll files at this location:

[OraFAQ: Problem with Reports 6i & Oracle 9i & Vista 64-bit](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/124421/0/)

Comment: I am glad you got a workaround. If you continue to run into problems, however, i highly recommend you look into upgrading to 11gR2 Forms and Reports. This is the latest and greatest version from Oracle. An important note also is that Forms 6i is no longer supported by Oracle - nor is it supported to run on Windows Server 2008 64-bit.

Thank you,

Gavin
http://www.pitss.com